# A Delimiter Error

Tags: delimiters

LaTeX indicates a delimiter error for the following written code. Please help me if possible.

```
    \begin{equation}
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}}\exp \biggl⁡[(z^{2}+z'^{2})+\frac{2zz't- 
    (z^{2}+z'^{2})}{1-t^{2}}\biggr]
    \end{equation}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a (invisible) Unicode codepoint U+2061 (FUNCTION APPLICATION) between `\biggl` and `[`. Remove `\biggl[` and rewrite it.